# Will Visual Studio Express for Phone 7 series mess up Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-express

I have Visual Studio 2010 professional installed.

If I install Visual Studio Express for Phone 7, will Visual Studio 2010 still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will work just fine.  Express versions of Visual Studio are designed to work side by side with both other express editions and non-express editions.

Note: I'm not sure what the state of Visual Studio Expressfor the Phone 7 is.  Occasionally issues will pop up when installing multiple versions of Visual Studio if one or more is a beta edition.  If that's the case I would proceed with caution.

Comment: Appears you mean "Express" when writing about express v. non-express versions. Could you edit and or comment to verify that you mean "Express" instead of "Expression" when writing about Visual Studio 2010 editions?  (To prevent confusion with Microsoft Product called "Expression")

Comment: @arrocharGeek yep, not sure what I was thinking.  Fixed

Comment: How can I install Visual Studio 2010 Professional and Express in parallel? I have Professional installed, but every time I try to install the Windows Phone Developer Tools, the Express edition only integrates into my Professional edition ... (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132464/how-to-install-visual-studio-2010-professional-and-express-in-parallel)