# How to Install Visual Studio 2010 Professional and Express in Parallel

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I already have Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed on my developer machine. However, I need to install Visual Studio 2010 Express so that I can develop commercial Windows Phone applications. (I only have a non-commercial student license from DreamSpark for the Professional edition.)

How can I do that? When I try to install the Express edition, it only integrates into the Professional edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not ideal but you could virtualise your OS and run it on that.

[vmware workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) or [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) for example.

Wikipedia has a great list of products similar to these [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtual_machines)